# Kafka Sending Message Using Key to decide partition vs manually

Tags: apache-kafka

Let's say for example I have this Employee POJO:

```
public class Employee {
  private int id;
  private String name;
}
```

And I want to send this to a Kafka topic with multiple partitions. So I can use the `id` field as the key to select the right partition. I can create a `ProducerRecord` like the following:

```
ProducerRecord<Integer, Employee> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", employee.getId(), employee);
```

This will send a message to Kafka with the key as a header field and the `employee` as the payload.

My question is if the key is already included in the payload, and it is a large portion of the payload itself, would it be better to calculate the partition number manually and send it like that?

So it would look something like this:

```
int partition = defualtPartitioner.partition(...);
ProducerRecord<Integer, Employee> record = new ProducerRecord<>("topic", partition, null, employee);
```

And in this way would omit the key from the message?

Comment: if all you want is to omit the key, you could just send the message without any key and default round robin partitioner will be used (no need to calculate a partition as you do)

Comment: Yes, but I want to keep the sequence. So multiple messages with the same ID goes to the same partition. Using default round Robin doesn't guarantee sequence.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do that, but there are limitations:

- You can't compact the topic
- Some streams operations require keys (like joins)
- Consumers will need to de-serialize the entire message to get the key, so you can't use key for efficient routing or skipping.

As long as you know the trade-offs, and you think that message size really matters... go ahead and omit the key.

Comment: Can you link to some docs on what Kafka does with the key? I thought the key was only used to calculate the partition.

Comment: @George you are right as far as *Kafka producer* is concerned. gwen is mentioning Kafka Streams which is not part of your question. A plain Kafka consumer will also have no impact whether you include key or not -- it will fetch same number of messages in each poll